# Web crawler(NYTimes) using Jsoup (Link within a link)

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I have been assigned an assignment to crawl through the "nytimes" website and display the most liked, shared, etc articles on that website using the concept of a web crawler. 
    I have made use of JSOUP to extract all the links from the homepage of nytimes. The code is as follows:

```
public static void processPage(String URL) throws IOException
            {

             Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
             Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
             for(Element link: questions)
             {
                String absUrl1 = link.absUrl("href");
                if(absUrl1.contains("nytimes.com")) {          
                System.out.println(absUrl1); }
              }
             }
```

This code was used to extract and display all the links containing "nytimes.com" but how do I parse all those links and extract links within that link and so on? That's what a crawler is supposed to do. But I'm not able to figure it out. I tried to call the processPage function recursively but the output I'm getting is not as the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a single machine, then a `Queue` is for you.

As you come across links in a page that need to be crawled, add them to the `Queue`.  If you want to be single threaded, you could write a while loop that reads from this queue.  Initially, the queue might have the NY Times link in it.  Once that URL is pulled and crawled, more URLs will be in the queue for processing.  You can continue this for all NY Times articles.

Using a `Queue` also allows you to easily multithread, allowing multiple threads to take from the queue, helping increase throughput.  Take a look at the producer/consumer pattern.

If a single machine isn't enough, you'll have to do something more distributed, like using Hadoop.  Yahoo uses Hadoop to have multiple machines spider the web at once.

Comment: Can you please help me with the algorithm? I still dont get it!

Comment: Sure.  What part are you having issues with?

Comment: The breadth first algorithm. I tried implementing it, but it does not crawl all the links in the website. it crawls only the links of the homepage. please help me with the algorithm and code

Comment: Perhaps you should try posting a separate question on BFS?  Without the code you tried, I'm not of much help.